# angular2 in memory API returns unexpected result

Tags: angular, service, in-memory-database

I am following the angular.io tutorial at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 and trying to write a function getYolo() which retrieves single objects from the in memory web api module.

```
@Injectable()
export class yoloService {
    private yolosUrl = 'api/yolos';

    getYolo(id: number):Promise<yolo>{
    const url = `${this.yolosUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as yolo)
        .catch(this.handleError); 
    }
}
```

the function is called in my component like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.yoloService.getYolo(+params.get('id')))
    .subscribe( yolo => this.yolo = yolo);
}
```

This code at first seemed to work **but when I tried to navigate to an object with an id of 0, getYolo() returned an array of all the objects instead of the object with an id of 0.** Using

```
getYolo(id: number): Promise<yolo>{
    return this.getYolos().then(yolos => yolos.find(yolo => yolo.id === id));
}
```

works for id=0 where getYolos() is

```
getYolos():Promise<yolo[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.yolosUrl)
    .toPromise().then(response => response.json().data as yolo[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But this is not what I am intending to do. How can I change getYolo() so that it returns my expected result?

Comment: i dont see any issue may be plunker will be great

Comment: I downloaded the angular tutorial and edited it until it was exactly the same as what I had written, but strangely, the problem was not recreated. I even checked line for line to make sure all the code was the same. My only guess is that something went wrong with how I installed the node packages or something else going on outside of the app directory. I got a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wLGcCK1IGlrYDppplIx1?p=preview) but I don't think there's anything wrong with what's in there. In any case I have something to work form now, so i'll be fine.